# How can you add a time dimension with Rasters in Julia?

Tags: julia, geospatial, raster

I am learning Julia, I work massively with geospatial data, and I've come across the Rasters package, which appears to be Julia's counterpart to R Terra or Python Rasterio. I'm curious about how to add a temporal dimension to a raster using the Rasters package in Julia.

I've successfully managed to import my raster data and establish a time sequence in the following manner:

```
using Dates
using Rasters, ArchGDAL


Create a sequence of dates 
dates = Ti(DateTime(1981, 01, 01):Month(1):DateTime(2018, 12, 27))

Import raster
raster= RasterStack("/rasterpath/raster.tif")
```

But I cannot find in the documentation how to add a time sequence after you read the raster, in their example they read the time sequence at the same time they read the raster:

> Their example:

```
using Rasters, Dates
lon, lat = X(25:1:30), Y(25:1:30)
ti = Ti(DateTime(2001):Month(1):DateTime(2002))
ras = Raster(rand(lon, lat, ti)) # this generates random numbers with the dimensions given
```

In R you easily add a time dimension as follows:

```
library(terra)

# Define the date range
start_date <- as.Date("1982-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2018-12-27")

# Create a sequence of dates with a monthly interval
dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "month")

# Import the raster 
raster<- rast("/rasterpath/raster.tif")

# Assign the time values 
time(raster) <- dates
```

In python you can do something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import rioxarray 

# Define the date range
start_date = pd.Timestamp('1982-01-01')
end_date = pd.Timestamp('2018-12-27')

# Create a sequence of dates with a monthly interval
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='M')

# Open the raster for monthly average GPP with masking
raster = rioxarray.open_rasterio("/rasterpath/raster.tif")

# Expand the raster with the time dimension
raster = raster.expand_dims(time=dates)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide an example file I cannot know for sure, but I'm guessing your raster already has a 3rd dimension that you want to replace by these dates
.

If this is the case you can use [set](https://rafaqz.github.io/Rasters.jl/dev/scripts/generated/basics/array_operations/?h=set#set). The 3rd dimension of a .tif file is always called Band, so in your case your code would be something like this.

```
raster_w_dates = set(raster, :Band => dates)
```

Does that work?